# How to exclude a subdirectory from an Apache URL rewrite condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite conditions applied to the root directory of my Apache2 webserver (in apache.conf)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

</IfModule>
```

I have a subdirectory, `www.domain.com/subdir` that I don't want these rewrites to apply to. How can I exclude `subdir` from these options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you just need to move up your last rule of skipping files/directories. Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# if request is not for a file/directory 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
# then skip from rewrites
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# add www to hostname
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# forward all the requests to `/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, could you explain the impact of your changes, so I understand in practice what this is doing please?

Comment: Sure let me add some comments for explanation.

Comment: check the answer now and let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: Thanks, so how does this allow the rewrite conditions to apply to the domain, but excluded from a named subdirectory (`subdir` is meant as a named directory, not all subdomains)?

Comment: You wrote `subdir` is a sub directory and if that's the case then first rule will skip it from rewrites since that rule has this condition: `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d` which returns true for a valid directory.

Comment: Ok, thanks, why do I not need `RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]` or `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l` are these repeated by the other rules?

Comment: You don't really need `RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]` and that is why I omitted it since we have much strong condition now: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` which skis all valid files (css/js/images etc) from rewrites.

Answer (score 1):

Right after this line

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Add:

```
RewriteRule ^/subdir/ - [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+subdir/
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, so `RewriteRule ^/subdir/ - [L]` excludes all rewrite conditions from `subdir`? what does the second option provide (literally)?

Comment: @alias51 Yeah, so any request that starts with `/subdir/` gets passed through the rewrite engine without any modifications. The second option is to affect *only* requests made by the browser, as the first option will also get applied when there's internal rewrites to `subdir/`. Not sure if that matters for your setup.